# Partial gauge fixing a point to infinity in conformal field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems, gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

While deriving the structure of a 4 pt. function in CFT, we write the conformal block with respect to the cross ratios
$$ u = \frac{x_{12}^2x_{34}^2}{x_{13}^2x_{24}^2}, \; v = \frac{x_{14}^2x_{23}^2}{x_{13}^2x_{24}^2} $$
Then we take $x_1 = (0,...,0), \; x_3 = (1,0,...,0)$ and $x_4 \to \infty$. Then we have 2 unfixed parameters $z,\bar{z}$ for $x_2$ and rewrite the conformal blocks w.r.t $u=z\bar{z}$ and $v = (1-z)(1-\bar{z})$.

My question is, if we directly try to use the fixed coordinates in the expressions of $u,v$ we encounter infinities due to the $x_4$, how do we resolve that? Do we consider the infinity to be a point from where every point is equidistant and cancel the terms?

Suppose we have an integral

[image]

How do we resolve the issues in the denominators like $z_{i5}^h$ due to $z_5 \to \infty$ in this case?